# Kill a certain laravel artisan console command in scheduler

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-artisan

I got multiple console commands to be called in the background, when I use artisan schedule:list it returns all the jobs

[image: schedule::list]

I want to kill a certain task for debugging matters, or stop all the tasks, since there will be a command that fetches data will be run for days before it stops, therefore I want to be able to stop it at anytime to stop the load on the server or for debugging

I searched a lot and I couldn't find a way to do that

later I plan to make a console command to kill a certain command

my local env is windows, and the server is linux, I want to test on both environments before deploying online

thanks

Comment: probably a solution lies in the task regularly checking for some sort of file system flag that tells it that it should quit.  You would need to add this check inside any loop inside the job.  As for commands that take days to run, there is a big architectural issue there.

Comment: It takes days only at the beginning 

Its US a real state market, and contracted with a supplier with like 1 million+ properties, so i'm caching these properties to save time calling external APIs

so it takes long at the beginning, after that you cache most/all of the properties, it'll be easier since its only updating/caching new properties only

so its a kind of daily job or continuously job to fetch/update properties, but the time of it varies, so I do not want to fire such a thing without having the ability to hold/abort it due to the load it will make on the server
@Snapey